# Windows 7 clock out of sync?

Tags: windows-7, sync

I have Winows 7 Enterprise on brand new laptop (HP G2). BIOS is updated, every driver is installed. Clock in BIOS is set to correct time, Windows time have correct time. But after some time it is 20 minutes behind real time. Tried sync, but cant set sync every 30 minutes :( that would bypassed problem. Safe mode doesn't help, reinstallation of Windows doesn't help. What can I do?

Comment: After it's drifted off by 20 minutes in Windows, is the BIOS time also out by 20 minutes?

Comment: Brand new laptop? It's under warranty. Call support and request an exchange. Are all Windows updates installed? What have you researched? There are loads of search results for "windows 7 clock loses time".

Comment: what is the output of `net time` ?

Comment: Check this forum post. The issue could be due to some gadgets opened in your machine. The list steps to be followed are detailed in the this post. Try this out. http://www.joellipman.com/articles/microsoft/windows-os/381-windows-7-system-clock-is-constantly-going-out-of-sync.html

Comment: Is this machine part of a domain and possible getting the time from a domain time server?

Comment: BIOS time is correct.

I bought laptop without Windows and now have Win 7 Enterprise (genuine). All updates are installed. Yes, there are loads of search results, but nothing helps.

It was my first site that I checked.

Comment: No, it's not the part of the domain

Comment: I think I need to repair "clock.exe" or
find some addon for firefox that show internet time, not my system time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your laptop off for the night (or for at least 6 hours). When you turn it on in the morning, go into BIOS *before* you boot Windows and check the clock. (Windows automatically syncs the clock as soon as it connects to the Internet, which also corrects the RTC in BIOS.)

If it has lost time, the battery is probably dying (some laptops use a "coin" battery while other just use the battery pack to power the clock). If not, Windows probably has too many background tasks running to keep the clock from losing time. This was a known problem with XP even with fast (1GHz+) processors.

Also check the list of "Internet Time Servers" on your laptop (Right-click "Adjust Date/Time", switch to the "Internet Time" tab, click the "Change Settings" button, select a different time Server from the drop-down list and click the "Update Now" button.)

It is possible your laptop is failing to sync with the chosen server to keep the clock updated. Microsoft's time server gets slammed by about a million PC's every minute, so selecting a "less busy" Server might improve your odds of syncing when polled.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It looks like that your solution fixed the problem. Clock is good after 24 hours :) (before it was broken after an hour). Thank you, thank you.